# In flutter image from memory bytes or image from assets has more performance

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter to build an app. my app containing more image assets.
Which method is giving more performance to the app

1. `Image.asset('/image.png')`
2. `Uint8List _image = base64Decode(imagenJson); image = Image.memory(_image);`

is anyone can answer which is more better to use with larger number of images